# why can not i see onerror event in dbo.sysssislog table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, dts

I have run an ssis package and got error in one of the tasks(the task is inside a sequence container).But when I  checked the msdb **sysssislog** table i could not see any **ONERROR** event(ONERROR) over there.let me know what might be the reason.Please be note that this package has a task in the ONERROR event of the package and it runs  when ever an error happens in the package.

what is the difference between **ON ERROR** and **ON TASK FAILED**

Comment: What task r u performing  in On Error Event ?

Comment: there is an execute SQL task .this task select some rows from sysssis log and update one of my custom tables

Comment: after the error when i fire this query i could not find any rows reuturned select top 1
    source
  from msdb.dbo.sysssislog
  where 
      (upper(event) = 'ONERROR')

Comment: Did u check OnError Event when u chose SSIS log provider for SQL server

Comment: wonderful ...that was the reason!!thanks a lot

Comment: I have written my answer at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While selecting the SSIS log provider for SQL Server check the events which need to be tracked .I think you might have missed checking the ONERROR Event

Comment: when i selected the ONERROR event it is working fine.But let me know one more thing.Why does the SOURCE column of the SYSSIS log table shows the package name instead of the task name i mean select source   
    
  from msdb.dbo.sysssislog
  where 
      (upper(event) = 'ONERROR') shows the name of package instead of the name of errored task

Answer (score 0):

OnError is raised when the package gets an error for any reason (including a task failure)

OnTaskFailed is raised when a task fails regardless of the package status

You should be getting a error on the log. Maybe your configurations are not correct.

Comment: when i selected the ONERROR event it is working fine.But let me know one more thing.Why does the SOURCE column of the SYSSIS log table shows the package name instead of the task name i mean select source from msdb.dbo.sysssislog where (upper(event) = 'ONERROR') shows the name of package instead of the name of errored task

Comment: you should have on event for the task and on for the package